# How to make a discord bot kick members in Java?

Tags: java, command, bots, discord

I'm trying to have my bot kick a member from the server automatically if they send a message with certain words in it, not sure how to get started with it. I already have the bot itself set up and it has other commands, I just don't know how to make it kick players.

Comment: Which library are you using ?

Comment: Can you clarify? Sorry, I'm relatively new to coding discord bots and I don't really know what a library is, I'm coding it in Eclipse if that helps

Comment: If you don't know what a library is how did you make the other commands ?

Comment: uhhhh idk but how can I tell what library I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().contains("bad word")){

        event.getGuild().getController().kick(event.getMember()).complete();

    }

}
```